# Divide an hour of sensor data into 10-minute intervals in Python?

Tags: python, sensors, counting

I’m analyzing sensor data from a text file and creating bar charts of activated sensors in an hour using Python. I’m curious to know how can I divide an hour into 10-minute intervals on the x-axis and then count the sensors that are “ON”, and how many times they are on for? I would then like to divide this frequency by the total number of sensors that are on, so that I can get a fraction. I have created a filter that only checks and plots a bar chart of sensors that are “ON” between 07 AM and 08 AM, but I just don’t know how to divide this hour 10-minute interval. This is what I’ve tried so far:

```
#Import libraries
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

#Get user input
file_name = input('Enter File name: ')
file = open(file_name)
#Array of sensors
sensors = []

#Iterate through the file line by line
for line in file:
    words = line.split()
    #This line filters out the sensor data for the required time 
interval
    if (datetime.strptime (words[1][0:7], "%H:%M:%S")) > 
(datetime.strptime ("07:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")) and (datetime.strptime 
(words[1][0:7], "%H:%M:%S")) < (datetime.strptime ("08:00:00", 
"%H:%M:%S")):
        if words[3] == "ON":
            sensors.append(words[2])

count = collections.Counter(sensors)
print(count)

# Plot Graph and Set Y labels and X Labels
plt.bar(range(len(count)),count.values(),align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(count)),count.keys())
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Sensors')
plt.title('Motion Sensor Data')
plt.show()
```

The data in the text file looks like this:

```
2009-02-02  07:15:16.575809 M35 ON  R1_Bed_to_Toilet begin
2009-02-02  07:15:21.408519 AD1-A   2.82231
2009-02-02  07:15:22.532789 M35 OFF
2009-02-02  07:15:23.345479 M35 ON
2009-02-02  07:15:27.529299 AD1-A   2.79926
2009-02-02  07:15:28.655329 M34 ON
2009-02-02  07:15:32.57429  M34 OFF
2009-02-02  07:15:32.739629 M35 OFF
2009-02-02  07:15:32.931449 M34 OFF
2009-02-02  07:15:33.07573  M35 OFF
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Function *mapTime* get a datatime and map into the last minute interval argument (10 in your case). I read the file according to the format that you say.

```
import datetime
import time

def mapTime(dt , interval):
    ts = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
    newTime = ts - ((dt.minute % interval) * 60) - dt.second
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(newTime)
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')


f = open('data', 'r')


temp = ''
for line in f.readlines():
    temp = line.split()
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(temp[0] + ' ' + temp[1].split('.')[0] , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print mapTime(dt, 10)
```

**Example** of mapTime function output:

```
2009-02-02 07:14:22 --> 2009-02-02 07:10:00
2009-02-02 07:22:09 --> 2009-02-02 07:20:00
2009-02-02 07:59:59 --> 2009-02-02 07:50:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you want to count the "ON" state of every 10 minutes. You should try the `resample` method of pandas.

First read the file into dataframe and create DatetimeIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(filename,header=None,sep=' ')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0]+df.iloc[:,1],format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Then count it using `resample`. Here it is counted every 10 seconds since you provided only seconds of data. Change it to 600 if you want to count 10 minutes:

```
count = (df.iloc[:,3]=='ON').astype(int)
sensor_list = pd.unique(df.iloc[:,2])
statistics = pd.DataFrame({sensor:count[df.iloc[:,2]==sensor for sensor in sensor_list].resample('10S').sum()})
statistics = statistics.fillna(0)

# plotting the first 10S:
statistics.iloc[0].plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```